# ios:Send out going calls using twilio

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-php

I am developing app that has to make the out going calls using twilio and send sms too from the application. I have a sample code given in the twilio website and  need to test the twilio by using the sample numbers so is there any possible URL to test with the sample out going call.

These are the following requirements for my application:

1. make an out going call.
2. send an sms to multiple numbers at a
   time.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking.  Can you post the code that you have tried and what did or didn't work?

Comment: you need to create capabilities Token first

Comment: Please refer my this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402829/twilio-crash-while-building-the-app-in-device-in-ios/31421923#31421923