# Twilio crash while building the app in device in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

I have added Twilio SDK and libJingleConnection through cocoa pods.

Twilio libraries like libssl.a , libcryto.a is getting conflicts with Libjingle_Connection libraries like libwebrtc.a so twilio is crashing.. Without integrating libjingle_connection.

Twilio integration is working fine.!

It is similar to below problem

[When using Twilio iOS sdk and building Cordova app openssl crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012159/when-using-twilio-ios-sdk-and-building-cordova-app-openssl-crashes)

But I need to keep both libjingle_connection and twilio in my project.

When I build the app in device. My app is crashing as below..

[image: Twilio_Crash]

My other linker flags are -ObjC and $(inherited)

I am not able to find the cause of crash..

Please suggest any solutions to fix the error..

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: please provide me all information , i am not able to get your question clearly .

Comment: what you need..! I have installed pod 'TwilioSDK', '~>1.2'
pod "libjingle_peerconnection" using cocoa pods. It is crashing when I build in device..!

Comment: Check build settings and , library paths and header paths

Comment: I will suggest the way i have did it ..

Alternatively, you may download the tar.bz2 file

from this line download code add resources headers and library folders to your new project ..  add twilio framework and then just add their path correctly in project , header search paths and library search paths .

Also other linker flags

Comment: Same issue is coming even I added manually without using cocoapods for twilio..as specified by you..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiii ,

Please Follow the steps to integrate twilio in app .

step 1 : import required Frameworks

[image]

step 2: Copy the Headers and Library Folders into Your Project .

Step 3: Add other Linker flags ( not only -ObjC but -lTwilioClient,-lcrypto,-lssl)

[image]

step 4: Add Header and Library search paths

Path of header folder you copied : $(SRCROOT)/Headers

Path of Library folder you copied : $(SRCROOT)/Libraries

step 5: Add prefix header file

```
#import <Availability.h>
#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

Make Precompile Prefix header to yes in build settings , and path of .pch file .

After This steps your project should compile and build , you can run it but , to use twilio you need to generate capabilities token .

step 6 :From Twilio's BasicPhone example copy basicPhone.h and basicPhone.m file in your project .

then in Appdelegate create an global object that we can access through out in project .

in appdelegate.h

```
@class BasicPhone;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{


BasicPhone *_phone;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic)BasicPhone *phone;
```

synthesize it in appDelegate.m file

```
@synthesize phone = _phone;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    /* iOS 8.0 later */
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                                   UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                   UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                    categories:nil]];
}   
self.phone = [[BasicPhone alloc] init];
}
```

step 7: capabilities Token :

Check this [Link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/setup) for how to generate capabilities token .

step 8 : create a makeCall.php file and in your twiML app (Twilio acc) set it's link for making calls .

step 9 : from xcode register with client .

In your basicPhone.h file

```
#define BPDefaultClientName @"abc"
#define BPCapabilityTokenKeyIncomingClient @"abc"
```

and in you basicPhone.m method you must have the function

```
getCapabilityTokenWithParameters
```

Change the urlString there with your capabilitiesToken url .

If you want both incoming and out going then your capabilities token url should be like this :

```
https://abc.herokuapp.com/token?allowOutgoing=true&client=abc
```

step 10 : in your viewcontroller.h login into twilio

Create an object of basicPhone

```
@class BasicPhone;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

BasicPhone* _phone;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) BasicPhone* phone;
```

in ViewController.m

```
@synthesize phone=_phone;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    BasicPhone* basicPhone = delegate.phone;

    [basicPhone login];
}
```

To make outGoing Calls :

```
NSDictionary* dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"xyz", @"To", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dictParams);
AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
BasicPhone* basicPhone = delegate.phone;
[basicPhone connectWithParams:dictParams];
```

This is how I did and Its working without any issue .

I will feel good If it helps .

Comment: I will check and let u know..!

Comment: Still it is crashing. twilio libraries is getting conflicts with Libjingle_Connection libraries so twilio is crashing..

Without integrating libjingle_connection.Twilio integration is working fine.!

Answer (score 0):

remove `-objC` from other linker flag. It worked for me

Comment: its not fixed..Even I removed -ObjC from other linker flags..!

Comment: make sure you removed -ObjC flag from Xcode build setting as well as  Pods.debug.xcconfig and Pods.release.xcconfig